# Слушатель на закрытие SearchView

Tags: android, android-search-view

После набора текста в `SerchView` в правой его части появляется кнопка закрыть `[x]`. После нажатия на нее, введенный текст стирается, `SearchView` закрывается. Необходимо было установить слушатель на это самое закрытие.

Пробовал так.

```
//слушатель на закрытие searchView
searchViewFilterText.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onClose() {
        Log.i("LOG_TAG", "searchViewFilterText.setOnCloseListener   - ");
        //...
        return false;
    }
});
```

не срабатывает.

В случае если бы я реализовывал  `public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` помогло бы

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
    Log.i("LOG_TAG", "onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item)   - ");
    //...
    return true;
}
```

Есть способ еще как отследить закрытие `SearchView`?

Answer (score 0):

Помогло вот так:

```
SearchView searchViewFilterText = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);

// запрашиваем id кнопки [x] внутри searchView
int searchCloseButtonId = searchViewFilterText.getContext().getResources()
        .getIdentifier("android:id/search_close_btn", null, null);
ImageView closeButton = (ImageView) this.searchViewFilterText.findViewById(searchCloseButtonId);
// устанавливаем слушатель
        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              //выполняем действия, к примеру, свернуть клавиатуру, убрать фокус
            }
        });
```

Comment: Используйте `AppCompatSearchView` + `Toolbar`, там таких проблем вообще нет